# Can I access the width and height from a Windows RECT struct without calculating it?

Tags: c++, c, windows

After passing a pointer to a [`RECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd162897(v=vs.85)) struct to `AdjustWindowRect()`, Windows fills out the `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` fields for me. I can easily enough calculate the width and the height I need from the fields, but I noticed something in the Visual Studio debugger. In the Value column of the Watch window, the value for the `RECT` variable (`AdjustedWindowRect`) shows a grouping of the fields that I'm not used to (`LT` & `RB`, which I assume to mean left/top & right/bottom) and also displays the width and height in braces at the end. Is this just a feature of the debugger, or can I access the width and height values from the struct without having to do the calculations in the code?

[image]

Comment: The width and height displayed by the debugger is *calculated* by the debugger.

Comment: Also by looking at the declaration in the link you provide, the `struct` is a C `struct` with a `typedef` to `RECT` and `*PRECT`, so there is no possibility of there being a `LT` private member not disclosed by the API.

Comment: Probably a Visual Studio debugger extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t. It’s formatted by the debugger. Specifically, see this XML:

```
<Type Name="tagRECT">
    <AlternativeType Name="CRect"></AlternativeType>
    <DisplayString>{{LT({left}, {top}) RB({right}, {bottom})  [{right-left} x {bottom-top}]}}</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

That code is from in `windows.natvis` file, on my PC it’s in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\`.

BTW, you can easily add custom visualizers for your own types, write a similar *.natvis file, include in project, and the IDE will use it for debugging.

Comment: wonderfully detailed answer. Found the file on my system. Thank you.